# Monitoring Reasoning Progress using the Pellet Reasoner

Tags: java, semantic-web, ontology, pellet, reasoning

I am currently constructing an OWL ontology, which - until very recently classified rapidly using the Pellet reasoner. However, since the introduction of several new classes, the reasoning performance has slowed to a crawl. Although the reasoner completes and the ontology does not contain any unsatisfiable concepts etc, the time the reasoning takes is unacceptable. I am currently trying to track down the offending classes/class that may have led to the slowdown.

Here's my question: is it possible to log the reasoning progreess of Pellet? I.e. is it possible to produce some output that will document how long pellet has spent on certain reasoning tasks/traces how long reasoning over any given class and axiom takes? If so, does anyone have some java code they could post up?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bill Barnhill has provided [an incredibly helpful answer to this question](http://www.semanticoverflow.com/questions/858/logging-of-pellet-reasoning) over on Semantic Overflow. Please head on over!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using Pellet's lint tool to diagnose the slowndown in reasoning performance? You will also have better luck getting an answer to this question by posting it on the pellet-users mailing list, including the ontology that's causing problems or some subset of it which can be used to reproduce the slowness. You also don't say which version you're using, etc.